# "Missing EOF" Error message when querying using the spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: cassandra, cql, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to query a cassandra table using the spark-cassandra-connector using the following statements:

```
sc.cassandraTable("citizens","records")
  .select("identifier","name")
  .where( "name='Alice' or name='Bob' ")
```

And I get this error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 81.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.3 in stage 81.0 (TID 9199, mydomain): 
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of 
SELECT "identifier", "name" FROM "citizens"."records" WHERE token("id") > ? AND token("id") <= ? AND name='Alice' or name='Bob'   LIMIT 10 ALLOW FILTERING:
line 1:127 missing EOF at 'or' (...<= ? AND name='Alice' [or] name...)
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I make an `or` query using the `where` clause of the connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OR` clause is not valid CQL. For this few key values (I'm assuming `name` is a key) you can use an `IN` clause.

```
.where( "name in ('Alice', 'Bob') ")
```

The `where` clause is used for pushing down `CQL` to Cassandra so only valid `CQL` can go inside it. If you are looking to do a Spark Side Sql-Like syntax check out SparkSql and Datasets.

Comment: Actually `name` is not the primary key, just some column in the table.  I get this error message when I run your suggestion `LIMIT 10 ALLOW FILTERING: IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (name) is not yet supported`. The values for `name` are not unique. There are many different entries that share the `name` field. Is there any other way to leverage the connector for this or this is something only spark sql can do?

Comment: If Name is just a random column then the connector is just going to be used for fully loading this table. There is no way for the connector to find these values more efficently than Spark. You should look into the various Spark Joins if your set of "In values" is large enough.

Comment: Ok, I understand now this is outside the scope of the connector. Thank you!